# R: Looping through a single value vs. calling a single value speed

Tags: r

I was curious whether using a loop is any slow than using the call itself, but system.time() shows 0 time required for both:

```
# Approach 1
system.time(for (i in 9) { print(i)})

# Approach 2 
system.time(print(9))
```

Is one of the above faster than the other? In the extreme case, we could think of looping through a large sequence of numbers using approach 1 versus typing a line of code for each element of the sequence in approach 2 - which is quicker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure this comparison makes much sense, but in any case you should use a tool such as the `microbenchmark` package, which measures in microseconds and provides maximum, minimum, median, and average times over a number of replications of each call, to get some valid data. Here is the code for 1000 replications:

```
install.packages('microbenchmark')
library(microbenchmark)

tm <- microbenchmark(print(9),
                     for (i in 9) {print(i)}, times=1000L)
```

In my machine, the results in `tm` are:

```
Unit: microseconds
                          expr      min       lq       mean    median        uq       max neval
                      print(9)   23.091   26.744   44.18516   30.8455   46.7965  2662.311  1000
 for (i in 9) {     print(i) } 1302.230 1537.527 2031.22907 1727.5895 2255.6765 12599.699  1000
```

As you can see, the loop is much slower.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you on a Linux machine? Asking because I get largely different results in Windows versus Linux.

Comment: No, I'm on a Mac. How are your results different?

Comment: On Linux, I get similar results to what you show here.  But on Windows, there is virtually no difference between the two.  It's quite strange.

Comment: Yeah, that is weird. I don't know enough about how these calls work under the hood to understand the difference, but from what you say something must work quite differently between Unix and Windows.

Comment: This was exactly my point. I wanted to see which is faster across multiple systems.